# show one thing insted of all with index with ngFor and ngIf

Tags: angular, indexing, ngfor

when i click on the "mer info" (swedish) i get the right index number in console.log. But on the website everything is showing. same when closing. What have i missed? the information is from an api, using observalbes and subscribe

```
<section>
    <article *ngFor="let m of showMovies; let i =index" >
        <p  (click)="over(i)">Mer info</p>
        <img [src]="m.imageUrl">

        <div class="containmovie">
            <p class="moviename">Movie:</p>
            <p>{{ m.name}}</p>

            <div class="showmore" *ngIf="showMoreInfo">
                <button (click)="leave(i)">X</button>
                
                {{ m.description }}
                År: {{ m.year }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</section>

showMovies: IData[] = []
  order: IData[] = [];
  checkOutId: number = 0;
  showMoreInfo: boolean = false
  toCheckout: number = 0;


  constructor(private service: MoviesService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.movies$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((dataFromService: IData[]) => {
      this.showMovies = dataFromService,
        console.log(dataFromService)
    })

    this.service.getServerData()

  }
    
      over(i: number) {
        this.showMoreInfo = true
        console.log(i)
    
      }
      leave(i: number) {
        this.showMoreInfo = false
        console.log(i)
    
      }
```

Comment: Your `showMoreInfo` is not tied to any single movie, but is used in all movies. So when you set it to true - it's set to true for all, and vice verse. You'd need to add a new property to each movie object, so that you can control each movie display. Can you share your `showMovies` example structure?

Comment: i have uppdated the question with the info in showMovies component

Answer (score 0):

Add new property to your `showMovies` object after `this.showMovies = dataFromService,`:

```
this.showMovies.forEach( movie => {
    movie['showMoreInfo'] = false;    
});
```

In `over` method replace `this.showMoreInfo = true` with:

`this.showMovies[i].showMoreInfo = true;`

In `leave` method replace `this.showMoreInfo = false` with:

`this.showMovies[i].showMoreInfo = false;`

Then in your template do:

`*ngIf="m.showMoreInfo"`

and replace `<article *ngFor="let m of showMovies; let i =index" >` with:

`<article *ngFor="let m of showMovies; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">`

and add trackByFn to ts:

```
trackByFn(index) {
    return index;
}
```

EDIT: you might need to change your IData type to include 'showMoreInfo'